# running asp.net solution containing multiple projects in iis

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have an asp.net solution containing more than 1 projects which are inter-related and each project have different configurations in web.config file. The whole solution is kept in a folder, lets say 'X'. I want to run the solution in iis. For that, I have created a virtual path in iis of 'X', converted the folder 'X' to an application, and created a web.config file in the root folder that is 'X'.

When I am viewing one of the project' default page in browser, it shows an error of 
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'app1.SiteMaster'

I have already compiled the solution. 
Please help... Am i missing some settings...

Comment: So you have applications running under the main app? Did you create applications in IIS for those as well?

Comment: Thanks James...
Initially I converted only folder 'X' to an application and referenced all the paths wrt to 'X' and so was showing error. Now got them rectified...

I had to convert the projects to applications
and rectify the paths in accordance to the applications...

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the application can't find the master page. Assuming that your projects share the same master page, you probably need to update the path to the master page to the relative path from the root.

Comment: Thanks James...
Initially I converted only folder 'X' to an application and referenced all the paths wrt to 'X' and so was showing error. Now got them rectified...

I had to convert the projects to applications
and rectify the paths in accordance to the applications...

thanks...